# htaccess, Redirect all requests to https://

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess, I need to redirect all requests from

`https://www.domain`

to

`https://domain`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache configuration, you will need this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply
This is working for `https://www.example.com` but not for `https://www.example.com/somapp/test.html`

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond HTTPS !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

This should do it

via [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[EDIT] swapped "www.example.com" to %{SERVER_NAME} so it redirects to same name you've tried to access, but via https...

Comment: Thanks poncha, But I need to redirect it the request from www.example.com to https://example.com. I need to remove www from domain

Comment: @user1298842 then put literal "example.com" instead of %{SERVER_NAME} .. or do you need a dynamic replace of hostname there? (www.anything.com into anything.com) ?