# .htaccess redirect to https

Tags: apache, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htaccess, Redirect all requests to https://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912655/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-https)

I have ssl installed over my domain, but still all of the url's are http and not https. I have  used some mod_rewrite options like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I'm getting The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: @jeremyharris  The questions are not the same, btw the answer is also not working...And you closed the  question It's too bad!

Comment: @user1706482 perhaps I misunderstood your request, but other people felt it was a duplicate as well. Rephrasing your question might help everyone to understand what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I am getting this: The page isn't redirecting properly